How to check if Kaltura Player is in full screen mode or not?
So im using Kaltura Player in a next.js project. Based on fullscreen of the Kaltura player i have to show something. So is there a way to check if the Kaltura player went in fullScreen and viseversa?
I tried to log the player instance and find anything useful but no results.
const playerInstance = getPlayerInstance();

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
